# Can I work alone on an extension of a paper that had multiple authors?

Tags: authorship, extended-paper

Is it permissible for one of the authors of a paper to work alone for the extension of that paper?

Comment: This sounds like something you should be discussing with your co-authors, not Random People on the Internet.

Comment: @RaghuParthasarathy: really? you go up to your coauthors and ask them if it's ok if they don't work with you on an extension of their paper? I feel like if having this conversation wasn't awkward for whatever reason then they would have had it already.

Comment: Yes, really. Life is full of awkward but important conversations.

Comment: @RaghuParthasarathy: I agree that this should be discussed with the co-authors at some point. However, I think it makes sense to ask an outside source first, to know what is common, know what to expect, and what is reasonable or unreasonable to say in such a conversation.

Comment: It should be clarified whether, in this question, "extension of [the] paper" refers to an extended version of the original paper, or a new paper that extends the work from the original paper. At least my answer would differ significantly between these two cases.

Comment: @Mehrdad The correct question is not "Can I work alone on an extension?" but rather "I have an idea for an extension; are you interested in continuing our collaboration?"

Comment: @JeffE: What makes you think the OP is interested in further collaboration for him to phrase it that way? He has every right to not be interested in it as any other coauthor.

Comment: @Mehrdad Regardless of whether OP is interested in further collaboration, it's still polite to ask. If the collaborators aren't interested, they'll say no.  If the collaborators _are_ interested, asking them to butt out is rude (and just as likely to result in competition instead of butting out), and not asking them at all is _extremely_ rude.

Comment: @JeffE: You're making this argument go completely in circles. Re-read my comment above which you initially replied to. Like I said at the beginning, if it wasn't awkward for him to ask, then he would have asked already. It makes no sense to be arguing with me about what he should do. Literally the entire point of the question is for him to figure out whether/how to approach the coauthors *before* doing so. *I'm* not the one asking the question, I'm just explaining why it's completely sensible for him to post his question for us here. If you have an answer to his question, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 41):

There is nothing illegal about this, nor is this publicly frowned upon.  After all, it's very possible for some of the original co-authors to simply not be interested in the extension.

However, your co-authors might see this as impolite, to say the least.  If you offer to include them in working on the extension and they decline, then everything is fine.  If you don't make such an offer to them, they might not want to work with you ever again.

Comment: In addition, I suggest to prominently cite the original paper on which the extended paper builds.

Comment: On the other hand, in the frequent case where some authors of the initial paper did not contribute much to the end result, it would be impolite of them to insist to work on the followup if they don't plan on putting in more work than they did on the initial paper...

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer.. I asked this question to know if my co authors can make extension to my paper where I have actually worked the most

Answer (score 6):

I once was in the situation that my coauthors were always "interested" in the extensions, but had little time, which delayed the whole paper.

After some time I began to write extensions on my own and tried to publish them, which, indeed, was bad for the relationship to my coauthors. They had the impression that I was working behind their back (which was somehow true) - while my impression was that I was much quicker alone.

Comment: Good to read some first-hand experience.

Comment: In this case it would be good to circulate the work to the (ex) co-authors, giving them some time to review it. Based on the comments/contributions that you get back, decide if to keep them as co-authors, mention them in the acknowledgement or drop them.

Comment: You probably are faster on your own. But if you are any good many want a piece of that cake....

Answer (score -3):

Are you (writing the papers) under someone's employ or as part of a contract with someone? Then supposedly you would be expected to make sure your employer / contractor is OK with whatever direction you go. If you are not, then you simply have no such obligations anymore.